# Inserting incremented number where no identity / increment exists

Tags: sql, serialization, locking, commit, insert-into

I am working with a table which has a number assigned to each row (nulls not allowed) in the 'entryorder' column

```
1
2
3
```

In order to insert a row I can do a `@@rowcount` and assign the result to a variable+1 then use that in the insert statement

Is this the safest way ?

Comment: No, its not safe at all, what if a new row is added in-between you looking up @@rowcount and using @@rowcount+1 ? - This is one problem identity/auto  columns are designed to fix, you should use one.

Comment: I assume the reasoning here is to allow you to use the ID as a sorting mechanism. I would highly discourage this. Just make another (calculated?) column for that purpose.

Comment: Use an `identity`/`auto_increment`/`generated always as`/`serial` column, depending on your database.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using?  "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Answer (score 0):

if you are not able to change column properties to identity/autoincrement, then use max function to get max value of the column and add one to it for the new row. instead of using @@rowcount

Comment: unfortunately I can't change the field - it ties in with a few different applications - is there any way to lock it when using the max function to not get any conflicts

Comment: lock the table before you retrieve the max value using table lock or set the transaction isolation level